# Spring not serving static content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to serve static content using Spring mvc:resource. The problem is that the static content is not loading. When I inspect my request I realize that a HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST response is return from resource (in my case and image).

mvc-config.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.videovix"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>App-Name</display-name>

<!--
    - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
    - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!--
    - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller.

```
 @Controller
 public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/","home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home ()
    {


        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }

}
```

home.jsp

```
 <img src='<c:url value="/resources/img/library.png"></c:url>'/>
```

Project Structure

[image: File Structure]

I have looked on other question and none of them seems to solve my problem. What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you use the url directly in a browser address bar, do you also get a 400?

Comment: Yes, that also returns 400 .

Comment: You must have a controller somewhere that is mapped to `/resources`. Let's see your controller mappings.

Comment: What version of Spring MVC are you on?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. Try to debug the `DispatcherServlet#doDispatch` method to see how it handles the request.

Comment: I actually have it up on github. https://github.com/mdennis10/videovixx

Comment: You are forgetting your `VideoWebservice` controller. I'm trying to find out why, but the `@RequestMapping` with no `value` attribute seems to have higher precedence than any other. Get rid of it or change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring registers a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` for handling resources when you use

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

This handler cannot return a 400 Bad Request response. You must have a `@Controller` with a mapped handler to something that matches `/resources[..].`. Spring will check the `@Controller` handlers before the resource handler.

Comment: I am going to edit the question and add the code for my controller.

Comment: This is weird cause as you can see there isn't any handler mapped to resources in  MyController.

Comment: @user2054833 Are you sure there is nothing else you aren't showing us? In your Spring config or in your servlet config?

Comment: I just added the entire content of my web.xml file and the only thing that I haven't added is my application context xml file as well as the xml configuration for hibernate